# Android Intent error in onCreate

Tags: android, android-intent

My intent does not work even though I've done it before. The drop down menu brings about four tabs. One of those links should take you to a tutorial page in the application. So in optionsmenu it calls tutorial intent when tutorial is clicked on the page. In the error log, it tells you the string: "It got this far". However, it doesnt tell you: "It got this far I" from the onCreate method on the second activity (last snippit of code posted here).

What changes need to happen to my intent code in order to link it up.

```
public void tutorialIntent() //toasts and takes you to the settings...
{

    Log.e("tutorialintent I", "It got this far");

    Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, tutorial.class);

    startActivity(in);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) { //since int IDS are 1-4
        case 1:
            Log.e("test", "tutorial intent pressed");
            tutorialIntent();
            return true;
        case 2: //clear
            settingsIntent();
            return true;
        case 3:
            aboutIntent();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class tutorial extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e("tutorialintent I", "It got this far I");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e("tutorialintent I", "It got this far II");
    setContentView(R.layout.tutorial);
    Log.e("tutorialintent I", "It got this far III");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


    menu.add(1, 2, Menu.FIRST +2, "Settings");
    menu.add(1, 3, Menu.FIRST +3, "About");

    return true;
}
}
```

---

THIS IS THE ONCREATE CODE FOR THE TUTORIAL.JAVA ACTIVITY:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e("tutorialintent I", "It got this far I");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e("tutorialintent I", "It got this far II");
    setContentView(R.layout.tutorial);
    Log.e("tutorialintent I", "It got this far III");
 }
```

Comment: what does your manifest file look like?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the tutorial activity in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Sorry Jayizzle, didn't see the other person's comment. Did I copy him/her?

Comment: I upvoted two of your comments so you should be back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

As someone posted just now and deleted his/her comment, one must put the activity in the AndroidManifest file.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.jakegosskuehn.couchto5k.settings"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```